# How to create find the freq of a column in aggregate function in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I'd like to do a groupby two columns and then create a dictionary which has the value and their frequencies as the aggregate function. This is how my data looks lik

```
A, B, C
-------
1, 2, V
1, 2, V
1, 2, B
1, 3, V
1, 3, B
1, 3, B
```

I want to groupby `A` and `B` and create a dictionary which shows the frequency of column `C`. This is how my final dataframe should look like:

```
A, B, C
-------
1, 2, {V:2, B:1}
1, 3, {V:1, B:2}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `value_counts` + `to_dict`

```
df=df.groupby(['A','B']).C.apply(lambda x : [x.value_counts().to_dict()]).str[0].reset_index()
df
Out[73]: 
   A  B                 C
0  1  2  {'V': 2, 'B': 1}
1  1  3  {'B': 2, 'V': 1}

df.C.str.len()
Out[75]: 
0    2
1    2
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: to_json is simpler i think @W-B  (lambda x: x.value_counts().to_json()).reset_index()

Comment: @W-B: how can I add another column with the size of the dictionary?

Comment: @H.Z. what you men the size of dict, you mean the length ?

Comment: @W-b: may I know what str[0] do here?

Comment: @H.Z. since pandas will convert the dict to pandas dataframe type automatically , so we need to put all dict we created to list to 'protect ' it , then your dict is in a list , we doing str[0] , select the first item of the list get the dict /